# My website can not be accessed from a computer outside my network hosted through IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am using IIS 8 and am trying to host my website through it. The link to it is: http:// 10.8.245.88/ and  I am only able to access it through other computers in my network. However, when I try to access it from an external computer I can not access it. Can you provide me step by step instructions on how to solve this issue. I am really confused.

Comment: Too broad - it involves networking (private vs public IP, routing, etc.).

Comment: Port 80 appears to be closed on your server. Depending on where you're hosting the server, you may have to enable port forwarding on your router and add port 80 to your allowed list on your firewall.